# Why doesn't sympy evaluate sin(n* pi) = 0 and cos(n * pi) = (-1)^n when n is defined to be positive integers?

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

When trying to evaluate a function f(x) with Sympy, the final output appears to keep sin(n * pi) and cos (n * pi) in symbolic form but does not evaluate them as 0 and (-1)^n respectively when n is defined to be positive integers. However, Symbolab appears to be able to do the above behavior.

Is there a way to get Sympy evaluate expression similar to what Symbolab does?

Minimal example to generate the behavior in Sympy

```
# Load libraries
import sympy as sp
from sympy import*
from IPython.display import display
init_printing()

# To turn off bugging warnings
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
x,L,pi = symbols('x, L, pi', real = True, positive = true)
n = symbols('n', positive = True, integer=True)

a_n_x = 2/L
a_n_in = x * cos((n*pi*x)/L)
display(a_n_in)
a_n = a_n_x * integrate(a_n_in, (x,0,2))
display(a_n)
a_n = a_n.subs(L,2)
display(a_n)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is on this line:

```py
x,L,pi = symbols('x, L, pi', real = True, positive = true)
```

This defines `pi` as a positive real variable, so it is treated just like any other positive real variable would be - in particular, `sin(n * pi)` and `cos(n * pi)` cannot be simplified, any more than `sin(n * x)` or `cos(n * x)` could be. The fact that you named it `pi` doesn't matter.

To fix it, use the symbol `pi` defined in the `sympy` module itself, which SymPy understands to mean the constant π. This is already imported in the line `from sympy import *`, so you just need to not replace it with your own variable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure `n` is an integer, otherwise the identity does not hold:

```py
n = symbols('n', integer=True)
trigsimp( cos(pi * n) ) # Prints (-1)**n
```

Comment: The question says "n is defined to be positive integers" so we can't tell whether this is the problem or not - please hold off on answering questions until the OP makes the issue clear enough.

Comment: @Dominic Price in my machine the result is stills showing up as cos (n * pi)

`
x,L,pi = symbols('x, L, pi', real = True, positive = True)
n = symbols('n', positive = True, integer=True)
px = trigsimp(cos(pi * n)) # Prints (-1)**n
display(px)
`

Comment: Full code: `import sympy as sy

n = sy.symbols('n', integer=True)
sy.trigsimp( sy.cos(sy.pi * n) )
`  and it simplifies to (-1)^n. Sympy 1.9

Comment: @creanion thank you so much, your code works and I figured out the problem. We needed to use sy.cos() and sy.pi to get the desired result

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the desired result, we have to use sympy.cos() and sympy.pi. The updated minimal reproduceable example demonstrates this convention in further details

```
# Load libraries
import sympy as sp
from sympy import*
from IPython.display import display
init_printing()

# To turn off bugging warnings
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
x,L = symbols('x, L', real = True, positive = True)
n = symbols('n', positive = True, integer=True)

a_n_x = 2/L
a_n_in = x * sp.cos((n*pi*x)/L)
display(a_n_in)
a_n = a_n_x * integrate(a_n_in, (x,0,2))
display(a_n)
a_n = a_n.subs(L,2)
display(a_n.simplify())
```

EDIT: 12/4/2021 based on detailed explanation of how pi is defined in SymPy by @kaya3